# Is there a method for incorporating a conditional clause within a Laminas Db Select join operation?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-db, laminas

I have been working on two tables (A and B), what I want to do is fetch data from these tables using a left join in [laminas db](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-db/sql/). The following code is of importance
`$select->join(array('b' => 'custom_table1'), "a.id = b.column1_id AND b.coulmn2_id = 1", array('b' => 'custom_column_name'), Select::JOIN_LEFT);`

The problem is that it gives `Statement could not be executed (42S22 - 1054 - Unknown column '1' in 'on clause')` at the `AND b.coulmn2_id = 1`.

The join must take it as a simple condition, not a table column. This query generated by the above code works in MySQL but in laminas it is emitting errors.

There is one thing the `b.coulmn_id` is shown in quotes `"1"`. It may be a issue. If it is how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is correctly identified, the `Id` is taken as column name instead of a value. The solution I found is using `Laminas\Db\Sql\Expression`.
Like:

```
$select->join(
            array('b' => 'custom_table'),
            new Expression('b.a_id = a.id AND b.s_id ='.(int) $s->getId()), 
            array(),
            Select::JOIN_LEFT
        );
```